# Apache Spark - Redundant JSON output after Spark SQL query

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

"I have done the following:

```
    DataFrame input= sqlContext.read().json("/path/t*json");
    DataFrame res = sqlContext.sql("SELECT *, Some_Calculation calc FROM input group by user_id")
    res.write().json("/path/result.json");
```

This reads all the files in the directory that start with a 't' and are JSON files. Thus far, OK. But the output of this program is not a JSON file, as I intended, but a directory called result.json with a as many crc and as many output files as the number of input files. This results in many identical files. Since my calculations are grouped by the user_id, my aggregate calculations check out, but I get just as much output files as the input files I have, and since the aggregate calculations have the same result, many of those files are identical.

First of all, how can I generate a single JSON file as the output? 
Second of all, how can I get rid of the redundancy?

Thank you!

Comment: _how can I generate a single JSON file as the output?_ - You cannot, or at least it is not possible to cleanly generate valid JSON file in parallel. Whenever Spark describes input and output this is more or less [jsonl](http://jsonlines.org/) and "single file" is pretty much not an option without things like `coalesce(1)` which are not a very good idea.

Comment: I noticed that after my query, the `res` dataframe has the multiple lines. So I guess groupby is not working as it is in MySQL? Also, I added `DISTINCT` to the `SELECT`, now the dataframe only has two lines, but I get 198 empty files generated and 2 with the data I require. I don't understand anything xD

Comment: It is expected behavior. Default number of partitions for DataFrame shuffles is 200. So if you have only two keys the rest will be empty.

Comment: But If I don't use the `DISTINCT` keyword, and there are 3 rows in the df, I get 3 files as the output.